# How does one transfer a .dev domain into route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I don't see an option to select .dev and I'm unable to transfer my .dev domain into route 53. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

The list of [Domains that you can register with Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar-tld-list.html) do **not** include `.dev`. Therefore you *cannot* transfer a `.dev` domain to Amazon Route 53.

However, you can point your existing .dev domain to the Amazon Route 53 **name servers**. This will let you configure DNS names for the domain without moving the domain registration to Route 53.

See: [How to integrate the third-party DNS provider with Route 53](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-integrate-third-party-dns-provider-route-53-milad-rezaeighale)